# submit instagram form phantom js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

```
    page.evaluate(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.querySelector("input[name='username']").value = "username";
          document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value = "pass";
          //submit button
          }, 2000);
          console.log("Login submitted!");
    });
```

Url of page: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/

How can I submit a form of instagram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is only one <button> on that page and it submits the only form you can just click it.

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector("button").click();
}
```